# How to find the smallest value in a 2d dynamic array

Tags: c#

> I am trying to find the smallest number in a dynamic 2d array but i have
> hit a block and cannot figure out how this is done. I have done all the set up and populated with values.

````
        using System;

namespace _2D_Array
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           // Create integers n and r and set up the 2D array

           int n = 5;
           int[,] a;
           int R = 50;
           int x;
           
           a = new int[n + 1, n + 1];

           // Create number input randomizer

           Random r = new Random();
           for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
               for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
                   a[i, j] = r.Next(1, R);

           // Print array with random numbers to screen to check set up is correct for i and j

           Console.Write("   ");
           for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
               Console.Write(i.ToString("00" + " "));
           Console.WriteLine();
           Console.WriteLine();
           for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
           {
               Console.Write(i.ToString("00" + " "));
               for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
                   Console.Write(a[i, j].ToString("00" + " "));
               Console.WriteLine();
           }
           // Get Search Value

           Console.Write("What's the value to look for? ");
           x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

           // look through the array

           for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
           {
               for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j)

           // If the element is found
                   if (a[i, j] == x)
                   {
                       Console.Write("Element found at (" + i + ", " + j + ")\n");
                   }
               }
           Console.Write(" Element not found");
           
   ```
````

> This is all i have so far. in the end i want to have the smallest
> value from a set of random numbers set in my 5x5 array.

Comment: Try assigning `min` with the first value in the array instead of 0. You could also initialize it with a value you know is larger than any value in the array such as `Int32.MaxValue`. Are you sure you want to use `<=` instead of `<` in your loops? Most normal loops like that would use `<`, but since a lot of your code is missing it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: What is `n`? And what is the type of `a`?

Comment: n is an int value and a is just the name of my array

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *format out* your code: hard to read code is hard to debug.

Often, we can *query* array with a help of Linq:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  int min = a.OfType<int>().Min();       

  Console.Write($"The smallest element is {min}");
```

If you want good old nested loops:

```
  // not 0! What if min = 123?
  // Another possibility is min = a[0, 0]; - min is the 1st item 
  int min = int.MaxValue; 

  // note a.GetLength(0), a.GetLength(0): n is redundant here
  // and there's no guarantee that we have a square array
  for (int r = 0; r < a.GetLength(0); ++r)
    for (int c = 0; c < a.GetLength(1); ++c)
      min = Math.Min(min, a[r, c]); 

  Console.Write($"The smallest element is {min}");
```